# Adding FlyTo link in KML description

Tags: kml, google-earth

I'm trying to specify a Placemark's description to have a hyperlink to another earth location, but not to another placemark. When the link is clicked, I simply want to fly to that location on the earth. I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried variations on the following KML tag below, but to no avail. The link appears in the balloon description, but doesn't change the view or do a flyto. Can this be done? Example below includes an MGRS position, which Google Earth's search bar understands.

```
<Placemark>
    <name>Untitled Placemark</name>
    <description><![CDATA[<a href="18S UH 27103 98673;flyto">Click Me</a>]]></description>
    <styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
    <Point>
        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
        <gx:altitudeMode>clampToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
        <coordinates>-76.99418723939422,48.82106388888889,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need another Kml file that contains the location, something like the following should work. Create the following file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml>
<Document>
  <LookAt id="Location1">
    <longitude>-76.99156472538761</longitude>
    <latitude>38.81988094612709</latitude>
    <altitude>0</altitude>
    <heading>0</heading>
    <tilt>0</tilt>
    <range>1010</range>
    <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
  </LookAt>
  <LookAt id="Location2">
    <longitude>-76</longitude>
    <latitude>38</latitude>
    <altitude>0</altitude>
    <heading>0</heading>
    <tilt>0</tilt>
    <range>1010</range>
    <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
  </LookAt>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Save that file to a public server (e.g "http://yourserver.com/your.kml") then simply link to that file and specify the Flyto behaviour.

```
<Placemark>
<description>
  <![CDATA[ 
    <a href="http://yourserver.com/your.kml#Location1;Flyto">Click Me</a>
  ]]>
</description> 
</Placemark>
```

If you add additional LookAt elements to the file with IDs then you can specify which look at to reference using the fragment identifier. i.e.

```
<a href="http://yourserver.com/your.kml#Location2;Flyto">Click Me</a>
```